# WoR loading screen change

Tags: pi-4, boot, windows

I have recently started using Windows 11 on my Pi 4B (https://www.github.com/Botspot/Wor-flasher) and I want to know whether there is a way to change the default boot screen (which has an image of a Raspberry and a loading symbol), to a gif/mp4/etc... of my own?
I have no issue with going around in the system files
Does anyone have any idea of how to do this?
Thanks in advance